# Oracle orapki - How to install?

Tags: pki

I need the Oracle wallet manager/orapki tools to create wallets, but I'm unable to find an installation for them.

I want to install them on Ubuntu (but Windows or any linux would also be possible).

Can someone give me a hint how to get orapki on my machine, please?

Comment: I realise this question is a bit old but when searching google "orapki max osx" this is the third link that shows up, just after Oracle documentation. Were you able to resolve this issue and if so how?

Answer (score 0):

orapki/OWM are the utilities which comes along with Oracle Fusion middleware.
If you install the same, you will get orapki as one of the utilities.

Answer (score 0):

I added path to orapki, Oracle home, Java home to the 'path' env variable and orapki works.  OWM is deprecated on version 12+

Answer (score -2):

Create an ORACLE_HOME environment variable that points to the install location of the Oracle client

Run the following command, pointing to the orapki utility under %ORACLE_HOME%\bin (in Windows) or $ORACLE_HOME/bin (Mac/Linux/UNIX)

Comment: While the original question is a little unclear it seems that the OP is actually looking for the original source to download.